# Getting duration of 2 times

Tags: java, calendar

How can I get the duration of two Strings in the format `YYYYMMDDTHHMMSS`?

I´m trying with using the Calendar class and checking the `getTimeInMillis()`. Problem I am having with this is that it is not consistent. Any idea what I am doing wrong?
Every time I run this program I get 40-70 lines of output to console when it should be none.

```
public class DurationTester {

    /**
     * Get the duration between two given times
     * @param time1 yyyymmddThhmmss
     * @param time2 yyyymmddThhmmss
     * @return minutes between time1 and time2
     */
    public static int getDuration(String time1, String time2){
        int yyyy1 = Integer.parseInt(time1.substring(0,4));
        int mm1 = Integer.parseInt(time1.substring(4,6));
        int dd1 = Integer.parseInt(time1.substring(6,8));
        int hh1 = Integer.parseInt(time1.substring(9,11));
        int min1 = Integer.parseInt(time1.substring(11,13));

        int yyyy2 = Integer.parseInt(time2.substring(0,4));
        int mm2 = Integer.parseInt(time2.substring(4,6));
        int dd2 = Integer.parseInt(time2.substring(6,8));
        int hh2 = Integer.parseInt(time2.substring(9,11));
        int min2 = Integer.parseInt(time2.substring(11,13));

        Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal1.set(yyyy1, mm1, dd1, hh1, min1, 0);
        Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal2.set(yyyy2, mm2, dd2, hh2, min2, 0);
        long milliSec = cal1.getTimeInMillis()-cal2.getTimeInMillis();
        long nonNegativeMS = Math.abs(milliSec);
        long seconds = nonNegativeMS / 1000;
        long minutes = seconds / 60;        
        return (int)minutes;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String t1 = "20130108T150000";
        String t2 = "20130108T131500";

        int errors = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<5000; i++){
            int duration = getDuration(t1,t2);
            if(duration == 104){
                System.out.println("ERROR: Should only be 105 ("+errors++ +")");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you step through your code in a your debugger, which line is the first to show something incorrect?

Comment: 1- Use `SimpleDateFormat` to parse `String` dates back to `Date` 2- Use [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) to calculate durations, much safer ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer And simpler, but the OP should be able to use a debugger too. ;)

Comment: There appears to be a drift your calculations probably coming from the rounding of dividing the `long` values

Comment: It seems to have been something strange with Calendar class. Dont know what.

Comment: @Grains The (main) problem is, when you get an instance of `Calendar`, it returns with the date/time it was created, **INCLUDING** the milliseconds, which you are not zeroing, this is allowing a drift to occur in your calculations when it starts rounding your values...

Comment: @Grains PS- See my answer for the long and boring explanation ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a [documented bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4488157).

Try clearing the calendar before set:

```
cal1.clear();
cal1.set(yyyy1, mm1, dd1, hh1, min1, 0);

cal2.clear();
cal2.set(yyyy2, mm2, dd2, hh2, min2, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use SimpleDateFormat API for parse your String :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss");
    try {
        Date date1 = sdf.parse("20130108T150000");
        Date date2 = sdf.parse("20130108T131500");
        System.out.println((date1.getTime() - date2.getTime())/1000/60);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    String t1 = "20130108T150000";
    String t2 = "20130108T131500";
    DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss");
    Date date1=df.parse(t1);
    Date date2=df.parse(t2);

    System.out.println(date2.getTime()-date1.getTime());  // time difference in mil-seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

i would advice to use the `SimpleDateFormat` for parsing your `String` to date object

```
SimpleDateFormat date_format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmSS");
Date dateParsed = date_format.parse(yourStringDate)
```

You can use the `Date.getTime()` function to obtain the date object equivalent in milisecond and perform the difference between two date object

Answer (score 1):

To start with, your date conversion is off `Calendar` months are zero indexed (that is `Janurary` is actually month `0`), so instead of begin `Tue Jan 08 15:00:00 EST 2013`, you dates are actually being converted to `Fri Feb 08 15:00:00 EST 2013`, which, in of itself, is not the source of the problem, but is of concern.

Instead, you should be using ...

```
public static final SimpleDateFormat SDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss");

public static int getDuration(String time1, String time2){
    Date date1 = SDF.parse(time1);
    Date date2 = SDF.parse(time2);

    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal1.setTime(date1);
    Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal2.setTime(date2);
```

To convert the `String` values back to `Date`

Now, to the cause of your problem...

Because you are setting the `Calendar` values using the `set(int year, int month, int date, int hourOfDay, int minute, int second)`, the calendar instance still contains the milliseconds it had when it was created (`Calendar.getInstance()` will return a `Calendar` set to the date/time it was created), but you are not zeroing out these values.

This leads to errors in your calculations

You shouldn't rely on `Calendar` or `Date` for calculating durations, they are unreliable over long periods, instead you should use [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

```
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(date1);
DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(date2);

Duration duration = new Duration(dt2, dt1);
System.out.println(duration.getStandardDays());
System.out.println(duration.getStandardHours());
System.out.println(duration.getStandardMinutes());
```