# Have a list of hours between two dates in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, date, time, datetime-format

I have two times and I want to make a list of all the hours between them using the same format in Python

```
from= '2016-12-02T11:00:00.000Z'
to= '2017-06-06T07:00:00.000Z'
hours=to-from
```

so the result will be something like this 
2016-12-02T11:00:00.000Z
2016-12-02T12:00:00.000Z
2016-12-02T13:00:00.000Z
..... and so on
How can I so this and what kind of plugin should I use?

Comment: `from datetime import timedelta`. Should be of help.

Comment: `from` is a built-in word

Comment: you cannot subtract `str` objects, use `datetime` objects instead

Comment: resulting range should include `to`?

Comment: should we truncate minutes/seconds/... if they are non-zero?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If possible I would recommend using pandas.

```
import pandas
time_range = pandas.date_range('2016-12-02T11:00:00.000Z', '2017-06-06T07:00:00.000Z', freq='H')
```

If you need strings then use the following:

```
timestamps = [str(x) + 'Z' for x in time_range]
# Output
# ['2016-12-02 11:00:00+00:00Z',
#  '2016-12-02 12:00:00+00:00Z',
#  '2016-12-02 13:00:00+00:00Z',
#  '2016-12-02 14:00:00+00:00Z',
#  '2016-12-02 15:00:00+00:00Z',
#  '2016-12-02 16:00:00+00:00Z',
#  ...]
```

Comment: sounds intersting and easy!
but how can I download it ?

Comment: `pip  install pandas` should do the trick, depending on what platform and version of python you are using.

Comment: I have downloaded it and it works! however when I print time_range it does not seem to be a regular list how can I convert it to a list ?!

Comment: Did you see my edit? The list comprehension `timestamps = [str(x) + 'Z' for x in time_range]`. Should give you a list of strings in the format you desire.

Answer (score 9):

simpler solution using standard library's [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) package:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

DATE_TIME_STRING_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'

from_date_time = datetime.strptime('2016-12-02T11:00:00.000Z',
                                   DATE_TIME_STRING_FORMAT)
to_date_time = datetime.strptime('2017-06-06T07:00:00.000Z',
                                 DATE_TIME_STRING_FORMAT)

date_times = [from_date_time.strftime(DATE_TIME_STRING_FORMAT)]
date_time = from_date_time
while date_time < to_date_time:
    date_time += timedelta(hours=1)
    date_times.append(date_time.strftime(DATE_TIME_STRING_FORMAT))
```

will give us

```
>>>date_times
['2016-12-02T11:00:00.000000Z', 
 '2016-12-02T12:00:00.000000Z',
 '2016-12-02T13:00:00.000000Z', 
 '2016-12-02T14:00:00.000000Z',
 '2016-12-02T15:00:00.000000Z', 
 '2016-12-02T16:00:00.000000Z',
 '2016-12-02T17:00:00.000000Z', 
 '2016-12-02T18:00:00.000000Z',
 '2016-12-02T19:00:00.000000Z', 
 '2016-12-02T20:00:00.000000Z',
 ...]
```

Comment: how to do same in java?

Comment: @Abhilash: you can ask a different question or take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664907/display-hours-between-2-dates-in-java)