# How to get year, month, day from a String format in Java

Tags: java, date, datetime, simpledateformat

I am working on a piece of work where I need to get year, month, day from a String in Java. The string is like that: `20170119T163048`

Where 2017 is year, 01 is month, 19 is day, 16:30:48 is time.

I implemented code like this below:

```
public void convertStringToDate (String string) {
    String dateInString = "";   
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat();
    Date date = formatter.parse("20170119T163048");
    System.out.println(date);
}
```

But seems like it does not work. Looking around and I actually found quite lots of similar answer but none of them really work for me so...

Comment: Try the format along the lines of `yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmSS` - or better yet, make use of the newer Date/Time API - for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119665/geting-duration-of-2-times/18120233#18120233)

Comment: yeah it works for me so far. Thanks.

Comment: Abd the more general dupe: [Java string to date conversion](//stackoverflow.com/q/4216745)

Comment: `LocalDateTime.parse( "20170119T163048" , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMdd'T'HHmmss" ) ).getYear()` & `.getMonthValue()` & `.getDayOfMonth()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You Shall always refer to the documentation.[Simple Date Format Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss");
    Date date = formatter.parse("20170119T163048");
    System.out.println(date.toString());
}
```

Comment: Oh it works, thanks. But may I know what is the 'T'? I think it was the main part that makes me feel confused.

Comment: 'T' denotes time in your time format string. Always worth going through the Official documentation - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Actually, in the context of the format 'T' means a literal, it expects to find 'T' at this point in the format.  For the ISO format, 'T' is the time separator.  The new Date/Time API have a number of ISO formats readily available ;)

Comment: wow a lot of upvotes for this answer

Comment: @ScaryWombat, yes, for a very straight forward question